# Socket Shutdown Close Errors

Tags: c#, sockets, shutdown

So I am trying to close a socket without closing it to the other side for reading.

My closing code is

```
    objClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    objClientSocket.Close(120);
```

The problem is that the application that is doing the

```
    objClientSocket.Receive(buffer);
```

Is getting an error that the connection has been forcibly closed. If I put a break point before the .Shutdown() and let my application on the receiving end run, it is fine. I thought that the .Shutdown() Method waited for the socket to be read from and emptied before closing? Am I assuming wrong?

After this I took out the .Shutdown() and the .Close() causes the same error.(Not surprised but thought I would get it out of the way.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ' I thought that the .Shutdown() Method waited for the socket to be read from and emptied before closing?': no, it merely enqueues a FIN to be sent, and the FIN should cause the receiver to get an end of stream condition. The reset is probably caused by the close timeout. I would get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is probably that the downstream end has decided that it wants to receive data that never actually gets sent.  It's been awhile since I've dealt with the particulars, but the socket API provides methods (I think one is "Select") which can be used to wait until "something" happens on a socket; once a socket says something has happened, one can see how much data is available (if any) and then process it.